# Annotate many to many relation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models User and VideoData. These two models contain the details of each user and watched videos by that user. I used many-to-many relation. Now I want to filter top 10 videos watch by number of users.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    user_email = models.EmailField()
    user_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    videos_watched = models.ManyToManyField('VideoData', through='WatchedVideo')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user_id']
        verbose_name = 'User MetaData'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users MetaData'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_id

class VideoData(models.Model):
    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    video_name = models.CharField(max_length=40) 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User_Video MetaData'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users_Video MetaData'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.video_name     

class WatchedVideo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field = 'user_id')
    videoData = models.ForeignKey(VideoData, to_field = 'video_id')
    time  = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True)
```

How can i annotate for top 10 videos and number of users watched those videos??

Comment: What is `time` in `WatchedVideo`? Is it the number of times a user has watched a video?

Comment: @cezar no time is watched time i.e for how many hours that video is watched.

Comment: Just a remark on coding conventions: it would be better to rename `videoData` in `WatchedVideo` into `video_data` to conform to the rest.

Comment: @cezar .how i will filter top 10 cities based on number of user...i used "User.objects.annotate(city_count=models.Count('user_city')) .order_by('-city_count'))[:10]"  ............ but always always i am getting city_count = 1 ..

Comment: Are you sure there are cities with more than one user in the database?

Comment: @cezar yeh there are cities with more than one user..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83887/discussion-between-cezar-and-naresh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Count function from django ORM:

```
    VideoData.objects.annotate(
        watches_count=models.Count('user_set')
    ).order_by('-watches_count')[:10]
```

Comment: Just a supplement info: the OP should assign this queryset to a variable, let's say `videos` and then call the number of times a video is watched like this: `videos[0].watches_count` for the first ranked video.

Comment: You can do it like this: User.objects.annotate(city_count=models.Count('user_city'))
  .order_by('-city_count'))[:10]

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov Not working always i am getting city_count = 1