# Annotate in Same model giving unexpected result

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have user model with below fields..

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    user_email = models.EmailField()
    user_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user_id']
        verbose_name = 'User MetaData'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users MetaData'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_id
```

Now i want to filter top 10 cities by user i.e list of top 10 cities with number of users in that city. I used below syntax but always i am getting city_count = 1..

```
User.objects.annotate(city_count=models.Count('user_city')) .order_by('-city_count'))[:10]
```

i also tried below syntax but same result...

```
User.objects.values('user_city').annotate(city_count=models.Count('user_id')) .order_by('-city_count'))[:10]
```

Where i am doing wrong??

Comment: Does it work if you use the second syntax but count 'user_city' instead of 'user_id'?

Comment: Your last example works if you replace `user_id` with `user_city` as @DanielRoseman suggested.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i tried that but not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is right, just fix typos. Replace

```
User.objects.values('user_city').annotate(city_count=models.Count('user_id')) .order_by('-city_count'))[:10]
```

with

```
User.objects.values('user_city').annotate(city_count=models.Count('user_city')).order_by('-city_count')[:10]
```

UPDATE 1, 2:

```
top_cities_queryset = (User.objects
                       .values('user_city')
                       .annotate(user_city_count=models.Count('user_city'))
                       .order_by('-user_city_count')
                       .values_list('user_city', 'user_city_count'))

top_cities = [{city: count} for city, count in top_cities_queryset]
```

Comment: this is working but always i am getting result of 10 users in one city....but i want top 10 city list based on number of users in that city.

Comment: still same result...getting details of users in city....means shorted user based on city alphabetically.....first i am getting all users list in new york city .....but city is here in alphabetic order i.e started from 'A' . I want different result like [{new york : 20},{sydney : 15}] like that......can we talk on chat...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this without a a model that has a relationship to `User`. Basically you'd need to run the query on another model, then annotate the user_city from that other model. It's a bit weird for your specific case.

However, you can do this in Python. Here's how I'd do it:

```
from collections import Counter
city_counter = Counter(User.objects.values_list('user_city', flat=True))
top_ten_cities_and_counts = city_counter.most_common()[:10]
top_ten_cities = [city for city, count in top_ten_cities_and_counts]
```

Comment: below is the complete ink of my models....actually i am using many to many relations..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538188/annotate-many-to-many-relation-in-django