# How to perform annotation in Django model with a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two Django models called **Restaurant** and **RestauranCategory**. The Restaurant model
has a many-to-many relationship to RestaurantCategory. Please refer to the attached sample model instances.

```
class RestaurantCategory(BaseModel):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   description = models.TextField()

class Restaurant(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=128)
    is_partner = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(
      RestaurantCategory,
      related_name="restaurant_categories",
      blank=True,
      db_index=True,
    )
```

Now what I need to do is to perform an annotation from **RestaurantCategory** to have a new column called restaurant_names and assign a single string that contains all the related restaurants' names. I have added a similar thing that I need to do,

```
new_data = RestaurantCategory.objects.all().annotate(
  restaurant_names=<should contain all the restaurant names in a single string>
)
```

Is that possible to achieve with annotating? If not what are the options that we can use?
I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538188/annotate-many-to-many-relation-in-django) StackOverflow question and wasn't able to good idea regarding my issue.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: @TrueGopnik it's PostgreSQL

Comment: Then you can use [StringAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg) or [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Truegopnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248443/how-to-perform-annotation-in-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-relationship#comment129361067_73248443) stated, you need to use [`StringAgg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg), along with an [F-expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). The `StringAgg` docs are a little weak though, and don't contain any examples. Here's how you would do it with your models:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
from django.db.models import F

new_data = RestaurantCategory.objects.annotate(
    restaurant_names=StringAgg(F('restaurant_categories__name'), ', ')
)
```